# Unable to start WAS

Tags: websphere-6.1

I wasn't able to start the WAS. Here is the startServer.log. Could anyone can explain me whats the problem..Thanks in advance.

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************ Host Operating System is Windows XP, version 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 3
Java version = J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32
j9vmwi3223ifx-20080811 (JIT enabled) J9VM - 20080809_21892_lHdSMr JIT - 20080620_1845_r8 GC - 200806_19, Java Compiler = j9jit23, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61
user.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1
Java Home = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\java\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\classes;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\installedChannels;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\lib\\ext;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\web\\help;C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v61\\deploytool\\itp\\plugins\\com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy\\runtime Classpath = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\lib\startup.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/j2ee.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\lib\tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\bin;.;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\MKS\IntegrityClient\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\MKS\Toolkit\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\MKS\Toolkit\bin\X11;C:\PROGRA~1\MKS\Toolkit\mksnt;C:\Orant\9iClient\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\orant\forms6i\bin;C:\orant\forms6i\jdk\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\sybase15\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase15\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\sybase15\DBISQL\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
Current trace specification = *=info:com.ibm.*=all
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[11/1/12 14:32:15:963 EDT] 0000000a ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info:com.ibm.*=all.
[11/1/12 14:32:15:963 EDT] 0000000a WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\config sreeNode01Cell sreeNode01 server1
[11/1/12 14:32:15:963 EDT] 0000000a WsServerContr 1   Getting WindowsService obj with: server1 and C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\config sreeNode01Cell sreeNode01 server1
[11/1/12 14:32:15:979 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic >  getWindowsServiceNameForServer() Entry
[11/1/12 14:32:15:979 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic 1   In executeCommand, args are: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\bin\WASService.exe -getServiceName server1 -profilePath C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1
[11/1/12 14:32:15:979 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic 1   Runtime.exec() returned process java.lang.ProcessImpl@72d872d8
[11/1/12 14:32:15:994 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic 1   retCode from childProcess.waitFor() is 0
[11/1/12 14:32:15:994 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic 3   exitCode = 0
[11/1/12 14:32:16:994 EDT] 0000000a WindowsServic 1   Trying to new up WindowsService using serverName=server1, winServiceName=null
[11/1/12 14:32:16:994 EDT] 0000000a ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0018I: The trace state has changed. The new trace state is *=info.
[11/1/12 14:32:17:025 EDT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the was61profile1 profile
[11/1/12 14:32:17:025 EDT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[11/1/12 14:32:19:307 EDT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
[11/1/12 14:32:19:369 EDT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log, SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\server1 should contain failure information.
```

Comment: "Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log, SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\server1 should contain failure information"

Comment: What @DanielLyons said.  Specifically, are there errors in SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, native_stdout.log, or native_stderr.log?

Comment: Please provide the log info from below path: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\server1 should contain failure information.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is due to invalid/wrong password at $WAS_HOME/profiles/profileName/properties/soap.client.properties

I do not confirm this is the issue, but the above password conflict will give the same error message, I have seen. server will start but will not get initialized.

If that is the case, Do this
$WAS_HOME/profiles/profileName/config/cells/cellName/security.xml 
1)search the string "enabled"
2)change the value as false
3)Login the console
4)set the credentials

Till you share the logs, difficult to confirm anything.